# On measurable cardinals

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

Let $\kappa$ be an uncountable cardinal and $(P(\kappa),\cap,\cup, ^c,\kappa,\emptyset)$ the Boolean Algebra of all subsets of $\kappa$.

**Fact:** If there exists a countably complete *non-principal* ultrafilter on $P(\kappa)$, then $\kappa$ is larger than or equal to a measurable.

**My question**: Is there a Boolean Algebra $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of $\kappa$, $\mathcal{A}$ of size strictly less than $2^\kappa$, and the existence of a countably complete *non-principal*  ultrafilter on $\mathcal{A}$ would imply that $\kappa$ is (added: larger than or equal to) a measurable/inaccessible/strong limit?

I am interested even in special cases, e.g. $\kappa$ is regular.

Comment: But then I wonder whether you are really looking for an equivalence ... for example, if $\mathcal{A}$ is any complete atomic Boolean algebra of subsets of $\mathcal{A}$ then your (new) conclusion follows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is very interesting in the case $\kappa^+<2^\kappa$.

For this case, recall that a cardinal $\kappa$ is [weakly measurable](http://cantorsattic.info/Weakly_measurable) if every family of $\kappa^+$ many subsets of $\kappa$ admits a $\kappa$-complete nonprincipal filter measuring them. This notion was introduced and studied by my student Jason Schanker in his dissertation. There are a variety of equivalent characterizations.

Jason proved that if $2^\kappa$ is larger than $\kappa^+$, then this concept is not necessarily equivalent to measurability, for he constructed models of ZFC with a weakly measurable cardinal, but no measurable cardinal.

In such a model, therefore, where $2^\kappa=\kappa^{++}$, we have measures for all the families of sets of size smaller than $2^\kappa$, but $\kappa$ is not measurable. So this provides a negative answer to your question.

Meanwhile, weakly measurable cardinals are necessarily weakly compact, inaccessible and much more, so there is a positive answer to the version of your question at the end where you ask for less than measurability.

Indeed, the existence of $\kappa$-complete nonprincipal filters measuring families of $\kappa$ many subsets of $\kappa$ is equivalent to $\kappa$ being weakly compact. In this sense, weak measurability is a generalization of weak compactness from $\kappa$ to $\kappa^+$.

Thus, if $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$, the answer to your question is no, since the existence of such filters for families of at most $\kappa$ many subsets of $\kappa$ is equivalent to $\kappa$ being weakly compact, which is a strictly weaker large cardinal concept than measurability.

Comment: I'm confused by the second paragraph --- does "family" mean "Boolean subalgebra"? If not, what do you mean by a filter on a family?

Comment: I mean a filter that measures every set in the family---one can without loss move to the Boolean algebra generated by the family.

Comment: So we're talking about filters on the Boolean algebra generated by the family? Or maybe the complete Boolean algebra, otherwise I am not sure how to interpret "$\kappa$-complete"?

Comment: It is a filter on $\kappa$, which is to say, a collection of subsets of $\kappa$, and it is $\kappa$-complete as a filter on $\kappa$, and it happens to measure every set in the family, which means for every set in the family, either it or its complement contains a set in the filter. So it isn't necessarily an ultrafilter on $\kappa$, but it is ultra with respect to the family.

Comment: If $(\kappa^+)^{<\kappa}=\kappa^+$, one can consider the $\kappa$-complete Boolean algebra generated by the family, and it will also have size at most $\kappa^+$. And then, you can view the filter as a filter on this algebra.

Comment: Okay, I see. Sorry to be so slow. But you don't get a nonprincipal ultrafilter on this generated Boolean algebra, right? So this seems to be not exactly what the OP was asking.

Comment: Why not? The only part of the filter that matters is what is in the generated algebra, and it is a $\kappa$-complete, uniform nonprincipal $A$-ultrafilter.

Comment: What if I start with a finite family?

Comment: Oh, I see. Weak measurability means you have the property for all families, so you can always add more sets, and we can assume that the family includes say, all bounded sets and all singletones, all bounded sets, etc. It is harder to measure a larger family, so you can make it larger without loss.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Your answer is a lot more interesting than I expected. I have never heard of weakly measurables before. I will look into Cantor's attic for the reference. Thank you.

Comment: This is a side question, but is the following true: $\kappa$ is weakly measurable iff every family of $\kappa^+$ many subsets of $\kappa$ admits a countably (versus $\kappa$) complete nonprincipal filter measuring them? Or is it a weaker notion?

Comment: If there was a measurable cardinal below $\kappa$, then you would have that property. If you insisted on a uniform filter, so that the filter gave measure zero to all bounded sets, then you'd have a better chance, but even in this case, it seems to me that singular $\kappa$ of measurable cofinality would have such filters. Even with regular $\kappa$ and uniform filters, if there was a $\kappa$-strongly compact cardinal below, you'd have such filters, without $\kappa$ necessarily being measurable.